# Creating a Staging VM in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a Staging VM for a site that's in production that I have just inherited. The site is running Wordpress/Woocommerce and has not been updated in a while. The VM it's hosted on is running an old version of PHP. Obviously, this all needs to be fixed up but I'm unfamiliar with GCP Compute Engine. Also any attempt to run backup/clone plugins crashes the site and requires a restore from the daily snapshot which is very annoying.

Is it possible to clone the VM/disk to a new instance, point that at a temporary domain, and test/update the site? I have been trying to do this for a while now without much luck any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating a clone of an existing VM is possible and quite easy.**

1. [Create a snapshot of the VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_zonal_snapshot). If possible stop the VM before doing this to ensure 100% accuracy - this way you will have exact snapshot of the drive without any errors. You can do it while the VM is running too if stopping it is out of the question.
2. [Create a VM from the shapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#restore_boot_snapshot) - select as a boot disk a snapshot that you've just created. Remember to [assign a static public IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) to this VM (unless you want it changed after VM restart and since you're going to do some configuration this would likely happen). You can change the VM's specs at this time too - nothing stops you from adding/removing CPU's, RAM etc. It may well be that your VM is underutilised and you can use something smaller to save costs. Or the opposite.
3. Start the machine. Now you can modify your WP configuration to point to a new domain. Depending on the SSL certificate - you can either use external one or the one provided by GCP (most convinient solution).

If you already own a domain you want to use for staging you can host it in Cloud DNS or at some other provider - just point it to the external IP you just reserved.

If you will be hosting your domain in the Cloud DNS then you will find necessary infomration in the [documentation about managed zones](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones) (domains).

You can also consider creating a new VM and setting it as a template for creating a group of VM's ([managed autoscaled group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances)) and creating an [external HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) in front of it. But this adds a little to the complexity so it's just my idea if you needed to handle a lot more traffic.

Comment: Thank you, I was finally able to get this running following your directions, not too sure what I was missing but this did it. I think I was getting confused with cloning disks.

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer helped you !